# Does anyone know why Data Explorer database (preview) is greyed out?

Tags: azure-synapse

Does anyone know why Data Explorer database (preview) is greyed out for me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears I have to create a Data Explorer pool using the Azure portal first before this service can be used.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you have found the answer yourself :)